# How to use StreamSubscription for posts?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hey there I'm trying to get my flutter app to display posts from the array in their group by using streamSubscription so that the app will refresh when a new post comes in. I know the function is wrong but this is the best I could come up with.

Below is my function

```
    Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>>getDocStream(groupID) async {

StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>? qn;
  List<DocumentSnapshot>? eventDocs;

    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    qn = firestore.collection('groups')
        .where('groupChatId', isEqualTo: groupID)
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .snapshots().listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        eventDocs = event.docs;
      });
    });
     @override
  void dispose() {
    if (qn != null) qn.cancel();  
    super.dispose();
  }

  }
```

This is my FutureBuilder screen

```
 body: FutureBuilder(
  future: getDocStream(groupId),
  builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: ((_, index) {
                List<Widget> tiles = [];
                for (Map post in snapshot.data![index]['posts']) {
                tiles.add(
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(border:  Border.all(color:Colors.black)),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(post['postText'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                            SizedBox(height: 5,),
                            Text(post['fromUser'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                            
                          ],
          
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                  )
                );
              }
              return SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                children: tiles
                ));
              }),
                
            ),
          ),
          isLoaded? Container(
            height: 50,
            child: AdWidget(ad: bannerAd),
            ): SizedBox()
        ],
      );
       
    }
    else{
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    }
  },
   ),
```

This is my firestore and the posts I'm trying to get as a stream.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a low reputation to comment. Instead I am writing as an answer.
As per the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) the future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for your help! so I should change the function and put it into initState?